# Getting Forbidden when sending messages from Teams to directline in Bot

Tags: bots, botframework, microsoft-teams, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

We are getting forbidden message exception while sending message from Teams groups to webchat.

Seeing the below error log in Azure bot channel,

Webchat: There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError

Directline : There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout

Teams : Error occurred while communicating with bot

But we are able to send messages from Webchat to Teams, Teams to Teams , Teams to Emulator.

Issue only when sending message from Teams to Directline/Webchat

Comment: Could you please share if there is any console log/error?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT , While trying to send the message from teams to bot we are getting the below exception, {"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"}

Comment: What does "sending message from Teams to Directline" mean? What's the use case?